# Optimizing smooth tween between svg paths in JavaScript / React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, performance, animation, svg

I'm currently porting an application to React Native that captures user input as a stroke and animates it to the correct position to match an svg (pictures below). In the web, I use a combination of multiple smoothing libraries & pixijs to achieve perfectly smooth transitions with no artifacts.

With React Native & reanimated I'm limited to functions I can write by hand to handle the interpolation between two paths. Currently what I'm doing is:

1. Convert the target svg to a fixed number `N` of points
2. Smooth the captured input and convert it to a series of `N` points
3. Loop over each coordinate and interpolate the value between those two points (linear interpolation)
4. Run the resulting points array through a Catmull-Rom function
5. Render the resulting SVG curve

1 & 2 I can cache prior to the animation, but steps 3 4 & 5 need to happen on each render.

Unfortunately, using this method, I'm limited to a value of around 300 `N` as the maximum amount of points before dropping some frames. I'm also still seeing some artifacts at the end of an animation that I don't know how to fix.

This is sufficient, but given that in the web I can animate tens of thousands of points without dropping frames, I feel like I am missing a key performance optimization here. For example, is there a way to combine steps 3 & 4? Are there more performant algorithms than Catmull-Rom?

Is there a better way to achieve a smooth transition between two vector paths using just pure JavaScript (or dropping into Swift if that is possible)?

Is there something more I can do to remove the artifacts pictured in the last photo? I'm not sure what these are called technically so it's hard for me to research - the catmull-rom spline removed most of them but I still see a few at the tail ends of the animation.

#### Animation end/start state:

[image: animation starting state]

#### Animation middle state:

[image: animation middle state]

#### Animation start/end state (with artifact):

[image: animation end state with artifact]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specifics of what you are trying to do, but maybe you're looking for a 'best fit' curve rather than splines which go through all data points.

Comment: As far as performance, what's your test device? Mobile hardware is pretty limited compared to laptop/desktop.

Comment: @Abe iPhone 13 Pro. With safari + WebGL I can animate tens of thousands of points at 60fps. With react native + reanimated I can animate ~300 at 120fps.

I would expect browser performance to be much worse than (pseudo-)native

Comment: @SimonGoater best fit curve would be interesting! I think that would solve the artifact problem, but I would need too many points on a line to have it be smooth

Comment: I think William Candillon does something really similar when creating a Matrix like animation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49QR0wUDMG0)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [flubber.js](https://npmjs.com/package/flubber2)

Also why not ditch the catmull-rom for simple linear sections (probably detailed enough with 1000+ points)

If neither helps, or you want to get as fast as possible, you might want to leverage the GPUs power for embarrassingly parallel workflows like the interpolation between to N-sized arrays.

---

edit:

also consider using the [skia renderer](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/shapes/path) which already leverages the gpu and supports stuff perfectly fitting your use-case

```js
import {Canvas, Path, Skia, interpolatePath} from "@shopify/react-native-skia";

//obv. you need to modify this to use your arrays 
const path1 = new Path();
path1.moveTo(0, 0);
path1.lineTo(100, 0);
const path2 = new Path();
path2.moveTo(0, 0);
path2.lineTo(0, 100);

//you have to do this dynamically (maybe using skia animations)
let animationProgress = 0.5; 

//magic already implemented for you
let path = interpolatePath(animationProgress, [0, 1], [path1, path2]);

const PathDemo = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Path
        path={path}
        color="lightblue"
      />
    </Canvas>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yeah I've looked at flubber and flubber2, but I don't think I can/should import libraries into JavaScript worklets, so I'm limited to what I can do by hand. Although I've been thinking about how I can send package up the interpolation function as data and share it with the worklet that way.

Do you happen to have any idea how to leverage the GPU from a react native app?

Comment: WRT the smoothing of the line, the little artifact you see in the question appears for a single frame with the Catmull-Rom spline.

Without the smoothing, there are dozens of them 10x more severe

Comment: did i understand correctly, you get very bad artifacts when drawing linear segments instead of a spline? (seems like something else is going wrong then..)

Comment: In regard of GPU computing thats a whole topic for itself but afaik RN uses OpenGL which atleast supports compute shaders. (you would then create two (plus one for the interpolation progress) input buffers and one output buffer, and every thread would simply take the n-th inputs, interpolate, and write to the n-th output index)

Comment: could you elaborate by chance about the compute shaders? Do you have any links or references?

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty, because why let the points go to waste :) but yeah if you could elaborate, explain, or link out to more information about compute shaders in react native, it would really go a long way to help me

Comment: thanks ;)

i'll look for some helping resources and then as soon as i find some time (likely tomorrow)

Comment: sadly i couldnt find anything promising regarding gpu computing in react native without using platform specific code (which might be an option if your (time)budget is very large, but...) as you mentioned swift, i guess your main focus is apple devices, so here's their official way to write compute shaders: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu

Comment: you are correct, I'm only interested in iOS (not android) so that's not a problem. Unfortunately, I'm not a mobile developer so these docs are all greek to me. If you ever stumble across any GPU shader in React Native posts though, please remember me! :D

Comment: the app is a PWA which I can publish to the play store, and the performance is already fantastic (120fps on web). I'm just looking to make an iOS app without duplicating all the application logic, hence react native :)